# How azure ML give an output for a value which is not used when training the model?

Tags: machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to predict the price of a house. Therefore I added no-of-rooms as one variable to get the prediction. Previous values for that variable was (3,2,1) when I was training the model. Now I am adding no-of-rooms as "6" to get an output(which was not use before to get the predicted value). How will it give the output for a new value?
Is it only consider the variables except no-of-rooms ? I used Boosted decision tree regression as the model.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that when you train your model on a set of features and then use a test set to run predictions, **yes** it will be able to utilize/understand feature values that the model hasn't previously seen during training. If you have large outliers in your test set that would differ significantly from what the model saw during training, it will affect accuracy, but it will still attempt a prediction.

This is less of a Azure Machine Learning question and more machine learning basics (or really just the basics of how regression works). I would do some research on both "linear regression", and the concept of "over-fitting in machine learning". These are two very basic conceptual topics that will help with your understanding. Understanding regression will help you see why a model can use a value it hasn't previously seen to create a prediction.